# SelectNodes with namespace returns too much occurrences

Tags: c#, xml-namespaces, xmldocument, bing-api

I'm trying to process a response from Bing Maps REST Routes API.

The query is about a driving route with parameter routePathOutput=Point (i.e. returns the list of Point (latitude and longitude) values for the route’s path).

I need to select only 'Latitude' and 'Longitude' elements in the RoutePath subtree, but the SelectNodes method returns all 'Latitude' and 'Longitude' occurences in the XmlDocument.

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(routeResponse.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("rest", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1");

// This works fine:
XmlNodeList pathList = routeResponse.SelectNodes("//rest:RoutePath", nsmgr);
// ... and now pathList.Count = 1

// This doesn't work as I expected:
XmlNodeList latitudeList = pathList[0].SelectNodes("//rest:Latitude", nsmgr);
// ... because latitudeList contains all the occurrences of the element 'Latitude' in the  XmlDocument,
// not only the once in the 'RoutePath' subtree.
```

Thanks,
Carlo